# Firebase - creating two tiers of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase as the backend for a corporate situation where there will be clients who need to have access limited to the content they create; and employees who need to be able to look at all data. Is that possible in Firebase. I could not immediately see how to create such a rule if, say, I had an array of firebase uIds of employees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible in Firebase.

Given a simple Firebase structure:

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Rupert"
  uid_1
    name: "Buffy"
  uid_2
    name: "Zoran"

admins
  uid_2: true

data
  uid_0: "something interesting"
  uid_1: "look ma, no hands"
  uid_2: "Beam me up"
```

and rules

```
"data": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null && ( $uid == auth.uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists() )"
    ".write": "auth != null && ( $uid == auth.uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists() )"
  }
}
```

This rule will ensure the user is

```
1) authenticated and
2) the node they are accessing has their uid as a key
   or
   their uid exists in the admins node.
```

So Buffy who is uid_1 can only access "look ma, no hands" and Zoran with uid_2 (an admin) can access any node.

This probably could be simplified but it demonstrates the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase documentation has some [recipes](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/recipes.html) one of them shows a specific example of [role based security](https://gist.github.com/sararob/331760829a9dcb4be3e7) implementation